# ruby printing database content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in Ruby.
I have to render the database structure, using tutorial i found suitable code:

File index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing tasks</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Content</th>
    <th>Date From</th>
    <th>Date To</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= task.title %></td>
    <td><%= task.content %></td>
    <td><%= task.datefrom %></td>
    <td><%= task.dateto %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', task %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', task, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Task', new_task_path %>
```

Now i want to group tasks by 'date from' value, probably it means that in index.html.erb i should print only dates, and clicking on the date i should call another html file that will render tasks by chosen date.

this can be like

File index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing dates</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date From</th>

<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= !!! IF DATE NOT PRINTED THEN PTINT IT task.datefrom %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_date_path(task, date) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Task', new_task_path %>
```

Where  edit_date_path(task, date) should refer me to the index_date.html.erb, where i can get selected date and print tasks according to selected date.

Maybe i can get suggestion, it will be much easier is fomebody can help me with that, as task should not be very difficult, but otherwise i can waste quite a lot of time googling.

Thanks, 
Urmas.

Editing the question.

This helped a little. what i did now, i changed index.html.erb to

```
 <h1>Listing dates</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date To</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% dates = Array.new %>
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>

<% if ( !dates.include?(task.dateto.strftime("%m.%d.%Y")) ) then
    dates.push task.dateto.strftime("%m.%d.%Y")
%>

  <tr>
    <td><%= task.datefrom.strftime("%m.%d.%Y") %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show Date',  {:action => "index", :date => task.dateto}   %></td> <-- This does not work
  </tr>

<%
   end
%>

<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Task', new_task_path %>
```

Where 'Show Date' link link should be made to show_date.html.erb, where is correct code for showing records when input date is passed.

I had added in controller also method

```
def show_date
    @tasks = Task.find(params[:dateto])
    @dateto = :dateto

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # showdate.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @tasks }
    end
 end
```

that can be used in the not working link, to pass data to the  'Show Date' (show_date.html.erb), but i get errors all the time. The problem is with correct calling off the show_date.html.erb, code i will be able to write myself :)

Urmas

Answer (score 0):

in Tasks controller:

add a method

```
def index_date

@tasks = Task.all

end
```

and create a index_date.html.erb write

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>   
<tr>     <td><%= task.datefrom %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', {:action => "index", :date => task.datefrom} %></td>
</tr>
<%end%>
```

and in the index method in the controller change

`@tasks = Task.all` to

```
@tasks = Task.find_all_by_datefrom(#{params[:date])
```

This will list the tasks that match the date selected and everything will be similar as it is now thereafter.

Comment: Edited a question. This is not exactly what i require

Comment: @Urmas Repinski I'm not able to understand your question. Are you not able to click on the link and reach show_date.html.erb page? If the error says no route matches, then you need to add  - get "tasks/show_date" to your routes.rb

Comment: Added  :to => 'tasks/show_date'    for root, get  /home/urmas/sites/taskmanager4/config/routes.rb:56: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting kEND
        :to => 'tasks/show_date'

Comment: @Urmas Repinski if you need show_date as root you need to do this - root :to => 'tasks#show_date'

Comment: No. I want to have something different as root.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

It were necessary to add to routes.rb

```
resources :tasks do
  member do
    get 'showdate'
  end
  get "home/index"
end
```

add corresponding controller processing

```
def showdate
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  @tasks = Task.find(:all)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # showdate.html.erb
    format.json { render :json => @tasks }
  end
end
```

and to call it using (index.html.erb)

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show Date', showdate_path(task.id)  %></td>
```

All further processing is already in showdate.html.erb.

Hope this helps somebody.

I AM THE BEST!!!! xD